# Week Over Week change measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables, a date table that consists of the following fields:date, year, yearmonth, month, day, WeekNum
The second table Consists of the following fields: Name, Cost, Date.
The tables are linked by the date measure.
I want a dax measure that can give me week over week change in cost.
I already have a month over month change in cost measure but the same logic can't be applied here because "dateadd" does not give me "Week addition".

Week over Week calculation gives me wrong results.

```
Week Over Week = CALCULATE(
SUM ( UsageDetails[Cost] )
    - CALCULATE (
        SUM ( UsageDetails[Cost] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ('Date' ),
            'Date'[Year] = YEAR( NOW() )
                && 'Date'[Week Number]
                    = MAX ( 'Date'[Week Number] ) - 1
                && 'Date'[Week Day] = MAX ( 'Date'[Week Day] )
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a WeekNum function available to get a week of the year and then you do the math for WOW calculation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weeknum-function-dax

Comment: I already created the Weeknum field in my date table using the Weeknum function. I even included it in my dax measure above but it is giving me wrong values for Week over Week cost change.